# Is there any way to use "alarm tones" as ringtones?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, ringtone

I have the straighttalk Optimus fuel. In browsing" alarm tones" there are 2 - forest festival and morning cello I would like to make use as ringtones but they are not in that section... is there anyway to get them?

Answer (score 1):

If you are rooted, then with the help of any kind of explorers which allows browsing root storage, for instance, **Root Explorer**, open the Root tab, browse through **system/media/audio/alarms**... Copy the required files (alarm tones) and paste to **system/media/audio/ringtones**